# Mouse Action is not not working at runtime

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

if i debug same code then its working fine but when run this code then Mouse Action is not not working.
code are following -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("url");
        driver.findElementByXPath("xpath").click();
        driver.findElementByXPath("xpath").sendKeys("gg");
        driver.findElementByXPath("xpath").click();
        boolean saleIdVisible =driver.findElementByXPath("path").isEnabled();
        if(saleIdVisible==true){
            Actions mouseaction=new Actions(driver);
            WebElement payment_lk1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("path"));
            mouseaction.moveToElement(payment_lk1).build().perform();
            mouseaction.click(payment_lk1).build().perform();
            System.out.println("order id is not found ");
        }else{
            System.out.println("order id is  found ");
        }
            driver.findElementByXPath("path").click();
            driver.findElementByXPath("path").click();
            driver.findElementByXPath("path").clear();
            driver.findElementByXPath("path").sendKeys("95032");
            driver.findElementByXPath("path").click();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do 2 steps for that kind of action.

```
mouseaction.click(payment_lk1).build().perform();
```

instead of

```
mouseaction.moveToElement(payment_lk1).build().perform();
mouseaction.click(payment_lk1).build().perform();
```

Can you explain more about your : payment_lk1. Is this a link ? Button ? ...

PS : Take care there

```
boolean saleIdVisible =driver.findElementByXPath("path").isEnabled();
```

because a button can be enabled but not visible. ;)